# Command Shortcut text string format

Tags: wpf

I want to set my button tooltip by showing its shortcut key command.

```
<Button Command="Cut" 
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Command}"
            ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.InputGestures[0]}"/>
```

But, it shows the result:

[image]

It shows "Ctrl+X, Ctrl+X". I just want only a "Ctrl+X". Please help me. I am the beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the easy way here.

```
<Button Command="Cut"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
            Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Command}"
            ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.InputGestures[0].DisplayString}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep it simple.

```
 <Button Tooltip="Ctrl+X" Content="cut" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" 
 CommandBinding="textBox">
```

Xaml is above.

Comment: But for some command I don't know the shortcut key. How can I get the shortcut key without setting it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Your Xaml is correct. I think you use like this in code

```
command.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.X, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

You must check your code maybe double work.

I'm testing to write little code. But it is normal work

[image]

Comment: But I'm afraid that some command I don't know the shortcut key. How can I get it without procedural code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a converter can help:

```
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"  
        Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Command}"
        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.InputGestures[0], Converter={StaticResource KeyGestureToStringConverter}}"/>

public class KeyGestureToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static Conv Conv0() { return new Test.Conv(); }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((KeyGesture)value).DisplayString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I forget back on this. It works, but now I have a new solution without using converter. It just add .DisplayString after InputGestures[0].
 ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.InputGestures[0].DisplayString}"